# Why is the derivative of the real absolute squared different to complex absolute squared

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inner-products, absolute-value

I know that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} |x|^2 = 2|x| \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} |x| = 2|x| \frac{x}{|x|} = 2x $$
Which makes sense because $|x|^2 = x^2$, but for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ there is
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} |z|^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (z\overline{z}) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} \overline{z} + \frac{\partial\overline{z}}{\partial z}z = \overline{z} $$

Both makes sense on their own but shouldn’t they agree on the real part? Why are these two different?

This leads to the second part: which one should I use for
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial f_j} |\langle f_j,f_k \rangle|^2$$
Or does it depend on whether the inner product space is complex or real?

Comment: In $\frac{\partial}{\partial f_i} |\langle f_j,f_k \rangle|^2$ (I've generalized so the indices are all different), what are the $f_i$ and how is the inner product defined? If for example the $f_i$ are functions and the inner product is a definite integral, all that's defined is a [_functional_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), not partial, derivative thereof with respect to $f_i$.

Comment: @J.G. the f_j and f_k are defined as vectors in R^n or C^n. which is why I got confused which derivative I should use

Comment: Note that $f_{jA}f^\ast_{kA}f^\ast_{jB}f_{kB}$ has $f_{iA}$ derivative $f^\ast_{kA}f^\ast_{iB}f_{kB}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} |z|^2 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2 + y^2)\\
&= 2x
\end{align}
$$

No contradiction.  The derivative of $|z|^2$ with respect to $x$ along the real axis agrees with the derivative of $x^2$ with respect to $x$.

The definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is $\frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$.

This is why the factor of $2$ is disappearing in your computation.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial z} |z|^2 
&= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2 + y^2) - i \frac{\partial }{\partial y} (x^2 + y^2))\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (2x - 2iy)\\
&= x - i y\\
&=\bar{z}
\end{align}
$$

You might be confused about why we define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ this way.  For that see

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4529830/34287

Comment: so which one should I use for when f_j, f_k are vectors in R^n or C^n if these derivatives behave differently?

Comment: @SkyBlueSpace your question doesn't make sense to me.  Which one should you use for what purpose?  It entirely depends on what you are trying to do with these functions and their derivatives!